# Discount with event (onChange) Javascript not work?

Tags: javascript

I have Create Discount with  Javascript, this the Script

```
    <script>

            function hitung()
                  {
                    var x = document.getElementById('TOTAL').value;
                    var y = document.getElementById('DISKON').value;  

                    var besarDiskon = x * (y/100);


                    var grandTotal = x - besarDiskon;

                    document.getElementById('GTOTAL').value = grandTotal;

                  } 

    </script>

    <input type='text' name='TOTAL' size='20' id='TOTAL' value='200000'>
    <input type='text' name='DISKON' size='20' id='DISKON' onChange='hitung()' placeholder='Diskon'>    
    <input type='text' name='GRANDTOTAL' size='20' id='GTOTAL' onChange='hitung()' placeholder='Grand Total'>
```

It Run Well, but the All I need is the Text Box value get data from mysql

```
<input type='text' name='TOTAL' size='20' id='TOTAL' value='<?php echo $data[TOTAL];?>'>
```

If I run that Script, the Result is NaN.

Can anyone help me for this Problem.

Im very appreciatedn your answer

Thanks

Comment: where is the php code?

Comment: Try to add quotes: `<?php echo $data['TOTAL'];?>`

Comment: @jycr753 Ok, sory, The PHP is Only get data from database. on value=<?php echo $datap[TOTAL];?> let's say I dont have a problem to get database from mysql

Comment: @jycr753 it not work, I have try your Advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[live demo](http://jsbin.com/isOYadAy/4/edit)***

HTML (just remove inline JS):

```
<input type='text' name='TOTAL' size='20' id='TOTAL' value='200000'>
<input type='text' name='DISKON' size='20' id='DISKON' placeholder='Diskon'>    
<input type='text' name='GRANDTOTAL' size='20' id='GTOTAL' placeholder='Grand Total'>
```

JS:

```
function el(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
var $tot = el("TOTAL");
var $dis = el("DISKON");
var $gto = el("GTOTAL");

function hitung(){
  var tv = parseInt($tot.value, 10);
  var dv = parseInt($dis.value, 10);  
  var besarDiskon = tv * (dv/100);
  var grandTotal = tv - besarDiskon;
  $dis.value = dv +'% (-'+ besarDiskon +')';
  $gto.value = grandTotal;
}

$dis.addEventListener("change", hitung, false);
```

Comment: Thanks For your answer. I have resolve it. it my mistake, My data have(,) between number bicause I use FORMAT(TOTAL,0) AS TOTAL. After delete the(,) javascript Run Perfectly. thanks

Comment: @Uchsun well it was (almost) obvious you were pulling other than numbers out of your php :) but any way take a look at this solution.

Comment: Ok :) I have see your answer on JSBIN. Thaks a Lot